# What do these old symbols from set theory mean? (Large E, $\cdot$ and $+$ for sets, and $\ \bar{\!\bar X}\,non\!\geqslant\frak n$)

Tags: set-theory, notation, math-history

So, I'm trying to prove the theorems in this paper by Tarski:

[On Well-ordered Subsets of any Set, Fundamenta Mathematicae, vol.32 (1939), pp.176-183](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm32/fm32115.pdf)

but it is from 1939, and I don't recognize a few of the notations from a modern set-theory perspective. Here are the relevant snippets.

The big-E notation, and set multiplication: (I'm okay with using subtraction to denote set complement.)

[image: big-E]

More set multiplication, and addition with a singleton:

[image: addition and multiplication]

And the double overbar, fraktur script, and "non" before an inequality: (I assume the double overbar means cardinality, and the fraktur $\frak n$ refers to a cardinal number, although I'm not sure if these cardinals are initial ordinals or the ZF variety using the rank-minimal elements of an equipotence class.)

[image: set "non"]

Comment: I'm fairly sure $\cdot$ and $+$ represent intersection and union respectively. I am guessing $E$ and $\Sigma$ are analagous to $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$.

Comment: @EuYu Under that hypothesis, would the modern translation of the first equation be the following?
$$g(X)=f\left(\bigcap \{y\in X\cap N\ |\ y\notin f^{-1}(y) \}\right)$$
I wonder what $E$ is an abbreviation for.

Comment: That would be my personal guess.

Comment: I also suspect that the notation $A\,non\leqslant B$ is just a poor man's version of $A\not\leqslant B$. (Since this notation corresponds to the existence of injective functions, it is not true without AC that $A\not\leqslant B$ and $A\gt B$ are equivalent.)

Comment: This is quite strange. I'm fairly certain that $\mathrm{non}\leq$ simply means $\not\leq$ and similarly for the other variants, as I have seen $\mathrm{non}\in$ used in this way before. Since Tarski is making a big deal of sets being well-orderable, I'm not quite sure what he means by the "potency" of a set (the double-bar). On the other hand, he refers to things such as $\aleph_0,\aleph_1$ etc., so he must know about initial ordinals.[cont'd]

Comment: My guess would be that the notation $\bar{\bar{X}}\leq\mathfrak{n}$ means the existence of an injection $X\to\mathfrak{n}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ is an initial ordinal (I think the minimal rank representative idea came much later).
The E symbol is just weird. I have seen $\Sigma$ used for unions, but in those cases $\Pi$ was used for intersections. If E really is an intersection, why is its syntax different from $\Sigma$?

Comment: If I can prove his theorem as (re-)stated, I suppose that will clear up any confusion. ;-)

Comment: @MihaHabič In my experience, the notation $\bar{\bar X}\leq\kappa$ generally means that there is an injection from $X$ to $\kappa$ (and thus $X$ is well-orderable), while $\bar{\bar X}\geq\kappa$ means that there is an injection from $\kappa$ to $X$ (so $X$ may not necessarily be well-orderable).

Comment: @MihaHabič Also, I don't think his notation using big-E is inconsistent with his big-Sigma notation for unions, since a more direct translation would be:
$$g(X)=f(\bigcap\{y\ |\ y\in X\cap N-f^{-1}(y)\})$$
His union is actually an indexed union, so we wouldn't use a class abstraction for it (i.e. read $\bigcup_{Z\in Y}Z\in X$), but the intersection is not an indexed intersection (the bracket next to the big E is a wff, not a class), so the abstraction notation is more appropriate. (Side note: I was hoping $E$ was short for *Schnittmenge*, but it obviously isn't.)

Comment: Yes, but sometimes people do strange things, like having $\kappa\leq\bar{\bar{X}}$ mean that there is a surjection $X\to\kappa$. The two definitions are equivalent if $X$ is well-orderable, but not in general.

Comment: I think I've figured out the E thing. It isn't the intersection, but his notation for comprehension. Page 181 has some clarifying examples of use. E then probably stands for *ensemble*.

Comment: @MihaHabič Ah, that second example definitely provides support for the notation meaning comprehension rather than intersection. Please put your discoveries in an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer collects our educated guesses about this notation.

The operations $+$ and $\cdot$ between sets mean union and intersection, respectively. The symbols $\sum$ and $\prod$ extend these to indexed unions and intersections in the obvious way. From what I can tell this notation was pretty much standard in the first half of the 20th century.

The large $E$ operator seems to stand for set comprehension (in which case it probably comes from the word *ensemble*) and translates to modern notation as $E_y[\varphi(y)]=\{y;\varphi(y)\}$. There is evidence for this interpretation on page 181 of the linked paper.

The double bar $\bar{\bar{X}}$ undoubtedly means the cardinality of $X$, although it isn't clear how this is interpreted if $X$ is not well-orderable. It is possible, since the symbol always appears in relation to another cardinality, that the relations mean the existence of certain functions (probably injections) and the symbol $\bar{\bar{X}}$ by itself has no meaning.

It is likely that initial ordinals are meant when talking about cardinal numbers (written in fraktur). This is supported by the appearance of $\aleph_0,\aleph_1$ and others in the paper. Also, I expect it was much too early for the minimal rank representative workaround (which is basically Scott's trick) to have been known.

The symbol $\mathrm{non}\leq$ stands for $\not\leq$ and similarly for other relations. Note that $\mathrm{non}\in$ also appears in the paper.

Answer (score 6):

I would be very surprised if the Fraktur cardinals are intended to be well-orderable.  In those days, it was fairly common to distinguish between "cardinals" and "alephs", the latter being the cardinals of well-orderable sets.  Equations, inequalities, and algebraic operations for cardinal numbers were treated simply as abbreviations for statements about sets of those cardinalities.  I don't think people worried about getting actual sets to serve as cardinal numbers.

The double-bar notation for cardinal numbers goes back to Cantor. His idea was that, if you have a set $X$, you obtain its cardinal by two abstractions.  First, you abstract from what particular elements constitute the set; second, you abstract from the order in which the elements are given. (That implies, in contrast to how we think of sets nowadays, that a set is to be regarded as "given" with an ordering of its elements.)  Cantor represented these acts of abstraction by bars.  So a single bar was his notation for the order-type of a set, and double bar meant cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is too old. I only know:

> $\overline{\overline{X}}$ denotes the cardinality, i.e., $|X|$.