# How to read this older notation

Tags: complex-numbers, math-history

I'm translation a paper of Borsuk's from 1935, which is written in French. There is some strange notation. Based in context, I think this indicates the set of complex numbers with modulus between 1 and 11. Has anyone seen this before?

$$B = \underset{z}{E} [1\leq |z| \leq 11]$$[image]

Comment: It could be a typo for $1\leq |z|\leq 11$. That seems far more likely.

Comment: @Jeff: Would it be possible (and not inconvenient) to upload a small image containing the notation (and perhaps a bit of surrounding context)? (If so, please click "edit", then the "upload image" button. This will prompt you to select and upload an image. You don't yet have enough reputation points to post an image, but I or another volunteer can add the image once it's uploaded.)

Comment: I added the bars around the z. It was mostly the use of square braces and the small z subscript that confused me. I'll add a picture. The line in question is formula (2).

Comment: You can look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358991/what-do-these-old-symbols-from-set-theory-mean-large-e-cdot-and-for-se)

Comment: @Dario, Thanks, I had not seen big E notation before.

Comment: @Jeff Ford see also Kuratowski, Jaworowski - Topology vol. 1 where it is explicitly defined as set comprehension